# Remapping "Ctrl Shift Z" as "Ctrl Y" in Excel with AutoHotKey

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, autohotkey, remapping

I'm on Windows 8.1 using MS Excel 2013, and I'm using this AutoHotKey script...

```
$^+z::
    SetKeyDelay -1
    Send {RCtrl Down}y{RCtrl Up}
```

to remap "Ctrl Shift Z" as "Ctrl Y", in order to perform... edit >> Redo, in some Windows programs that use "Ctrl Y" to do so. So when I press "Ctrl Shift Z" in those programs AHK sends "Ctrl Y" instead and I get the Redo command.

But in Excel it only works if I'm working on *.xlsx, not if I'm working on a *.xlsb, if I press "Ctrl Shift Z" on a *.xlsb it doesn't work at all. Why is that?

Comment: AHK script can have strange behavior if you don't include `Return` at the end of a multi-line hotkey handler. Usually it will work correctly the first time and then break. So I'd start with adding a `Return` at the end of your script.

Comment: I added the Return at the end, it doesn't change anything, same bug. I have realized that the problem seems to be only on excel xlsb files, any idea???

Comment: Have you tested that straight up `Ctrl+y` works normally in xlsb files? And have you tested that your script sends `Ctrl+y` consistently in other programs?

Comment: Yes, it sends the keys in two other programs, just ok, In an excel xlxs it works to, I double click the "H" icon in the taskbar to check, it does send the keys, but in excel xlsb files, it causes a sound, like windows error sound, I double click the "H" icon, it didn't send anything. ThanksAdvanced.

Comment: According to [this](https://exceljet.net/keyboard-shortcuts/redo-last-action) `F4` is also a redo hotkey, so you could try `F4` instead of `Ctrl+y`

Comment: I tried the F4 and I got exactly the same sound and it does not send the F4 key, it seems to have a conflict with the modifiers, any AHK expert? thanxs anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the send statement to ^y.

```
$^+z::Send ^y
```

Excel may be beeping if it thinks `Shift+Ctrl+y` is pressed, which might be the case if you're holding shift down for the first modifier key and then sending `{RCtrl Down}` explicitly.

If AutoHotkey knows you're sending a key combo it will undo/redo the modifier keys for you automatically, but maybe since you are sending an explicit RCtrl Down it doesn't do that for you, and perhaps Excel just sees `Shift+Ctrl+z` and beeps.

Comment: answer here https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=17499

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    $^+z::
        SetKeyDelay -1
        Send {RCtrl Down}
        Send y
        Send {RCtrl Up}
    return
```